# Función en pandas u otra librería, que calcule maximo o minimo en rangos de una columna

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Buenos días a todos...

Me gustaría pedirles el siguiente favor, si conocen una función o funciones de alguna librería (como pandas o similar) que realice algo similar a la función que escrito. Esta función es muy lenta conocen alguna que pueda reducir el tiempo. Con 30 000 datos se demoro cerca de 2 minutos.

**PD:** *Si conozco algunos métodos para tratar que python sea más rápido, pero este no es el caso, necesito una función.*

Tengo un DataFrame, que llamaremos col, para nuestro ejemplo.

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    # Mi DataFrame es muy grande, este es para efectos prácticos X)
    col = pd.DataFrame({'valores':[4,5,7,8,3,5,7,0,1,5,2,7]})
```

Y necesito, extraer los valores máximos y mínimos de la columna (valores), pero en pequeños rangos, me explico...

Para el caso de los valores mínimos, y un rango de 3, necesito crear una columna que tenga, los tres primeros valores en cero, y el siguiente indice contenga el valor mínimo, desde el indice cero hasta el indice 4, un ejemplo puede ser el siguiente...

```
  #   datos          datos
  # iniciales       finales

      <MIN>           <MIN>
    0   4          0   0.0
    1   5          1   0.0
    2   7          2   0.0
    3   8          3   4.0   <-  Valor minimo en el rango col[0:4]
    4   3          4   3.0   <-  Valor minimo en el rango col[1:5]
    5   5          5   3.0   <-  Valor minimo en el rango col[2:6]              
    6   7          6   3.0   <-  Valor minimo en el rango col[3:7]
    7   0          7   0.0   <-  Valor minimo en el rango col[4:8]
    8   1          8   0.0   <-  Valor minimo en el rango col[5:9]
    9   5          9   0.0   <-  Valor minimo en el rango col[6:10]
    10  2          10  0.0   <-  Valor minimo en el rango col[7:11]
    11  7          11  1.0   <-  Valor minimo en el rango col[8:12]
```

Escribí la siguiente función

```
def rango_min(columna, rango, nombre_columna='<MIN>'):
    d_final = rango
    d_inicial = 0

    retorno = pd.DataFrame({nombre_columna:np.zeros(rango)})

    while len(columna) > d_final:
        retorno.loc[d_final] = min(columna[d_inicial:d_final+1])
        d_final += 1
        d_inicial += 1

    return retorno
```

Si alguno de vosotros que sois doctos en estos temas, conoce alguna función o algún, método diferente, para hacer el mismo proceso de manera más rápida os agradecería inmensamente, ya que he buscado y no he encontrado nada, no se como realizar una pregunta adecuada.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes razón... (lo siento)

La linea:
*retorno.loc[d_final] = min(columna[d_inicial:d_final])*

debe ser:

**retorno.loc[d_final] = min(columna[d_inicial:d_final+1])**

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas es [`pandas.Series.rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/window.html) junto a `min` o `max`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'valores':[4,5,7,8,3,5,7,0,1,5,2,7]})
```

> ```
> >>> df.valores.rolling(4).min()
>
> 0     NaN
> 1     NaN
> 2     NaN
> 3     4.0
> 4     3.0
> 5     3.0
> 6     3.0
> 7     0.0
> 8     0.0
> 9     0.0
> 10    0.0
> 11    1.0
> Name: valores, dtype: float64
> ```

Si quieres rellenar con ceros, simplemente aplica `fillna`:

> ```
> >>> df.valores.rolling(4).min().fillna(0)
> 0     0.0
> 1     0.0
> 2     0.0
> 3     4.0
> 4     3.0
> 5     3.0
> 6     3.0
> 7     0.0
> 8     0.0
> 9     0.0
> 10    0.0
> 11    1.0
> Name: valores, dtype: float64
> ```

Lo mismo para los máximos:

```
>>> df.valores.rolling(4).max().fillna(0)
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     8.0
4     8.0
5     8.0
6     8.0
7     7.0
8     7.0
9     7.0
10    5.0
11    7.0
Name: valores, dtype: float64
```

Si quieres un DataFrame como en tu implementación, usa `pandas.Series.to_frame`:

```
>>> df.valores.rolling(4).max().fillna(0).to_frame(name='<MIN>')
    <MIN>
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     8.0
4     8.0
5     8.0
6     8.0
7     7.0
8     7.0
9     7.0
10    5.0
11    7.0
```

Comment: waoo!!!

0.0352s para 30 000 filas. **FJSevilla, muchas, muchas gracias.** *Impresionante, tu solución es absolutamente estilizada.* Quedo muy agradecida contigo.